# Set http_proxy, https_proxy on Cloud Composer

Tags: proxy, airflow, google-cloud-composer

We are looking to run a DAG in Cloud Composer that makes https calls to a server outside the network that our Cloud Composer environment lives in.  Right now, our calls are timing out and we suspect it is due to our organization's rule of going through a proxy for any calls to external hosts. How do I configure my environment to use the https proxy?

I tried setting an environment variable `https_proxy` when creating my Composer environment and I got the following error:

```
    1) Environment variables [http_proxy, https_proxy] may not be overridden.
```

In short, I would like the virtual machines that are working for my Composer environment to know to use the proxy when making https calls. How can I ensure they use the proxy?

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: What have you tried so far on configuring the proxy of your Composer environment? The link that you have provided is not accessible to the public.

Comment: @RiccoD I edited detaling my attempted solution! If you have any thoughts, let me know..

Comment: How are you defining the environment variables? Can you provide the steps? Are you setting them in this [manner](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/environment-variables)?

Comment: Sure! Upon creating your composer environment you can specify environment variables, I did it here rather than adding variable to an existing cluster.

Comment: That error popped up when I tried to create my cluster (with the https_proxy env variable).

Comment: What version of airflow and cloud composer are you using? Have you tried creating the composer instance then updating the variable?

Comment: Hey @RiccoD ! I am using the following version: composer-2.0.25-airflow-2.2.5

And as for trying to add https_proxy to an existing cluster, I have tried that approach. I got the same error (screenshot included in my original question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From fellow friend at Google:

"http_proxy and https_proxy variables were recently added to variable blacklist. It is not possible to set these variables anymore, see the release notes here: https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/release-notes#August_29_2022 . This is due to the reason that it has led to environment stability issues in the past."

My fix:

I set `https_proxy` inside my task function. I used the python package, os, and added the following line of code at the very top of my task (task that made the https call):

```
Os.environ[‘https_proxy’] = “{proxy_address}”
Os.environ[‘http_proxy’] = “{proxy_address}”
```

This seemed to do the trick for me.